# How to perform multiple changes to a csv file without intervening writes

Tags: python, csv

I want to perform multiple edits to most rows in a csv file without making multiple writes to the output csv file.

I have a csv that I need to convert and clean up into specific format for another program to use. For example, I'd like to:

1. remove all blank rows
2. remove all rows where the value of column "B" is not a number
3. with this new data, create a new column and explode the first part of the values in column B into the new column

Here's an example of the data:

```
"A","B","C","D","E"
"apple","blah","1","","0.00"
"ape","12_fun","53","25","1.00"

"aloe","15_001","51","28",2.00"
```

I can figure out the logic behind each process, but what I can't figure out is how to perform each process without reading and writing to a file each time. I'm using the CSV module. Is there a better way to perform these steps at once before writing a final CSV?

Comment: Could you post your current code?

Comment: 2.00" should be "2.00" in your example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a set of tests and a set of processes.

If all tests pass, all processes are applied, and the final result is written to output:

```
import csv

#
# Row tests
#

def test_notblank(row):
    return any(len(i) for i in row)

def test_bnumeric(row):
    return row[1].isdigit()

def do_tests(row, tests=[test_notblank, test_bnumeric]):
    return all(t(row) for t in tests)

#
# Row processing
#

def process_splitb(row):
    b = row[1].split('.')
    row[1] = b[0]
    row.append(b[1])
    return row

def do_processes(row, processes=[process_splitb]):
    for p in processes:
        row = p(row)
    return row

def main():
    with open("in.csv","rb") as inf, open("out.csv","wb") as outf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf)
        outcsv = csv.writer(outf)

        outcsv.writerow(incsv.next())    # pass header row
        outcsv.writerows(do_processes(row) for row in incsv if do_tests(row))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is great. I didn't know you were able to create a list of functions to call. I learned a lot through this example, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simple for loops.

```
import csv

csv_file = open('in.csv', 'rb')
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

header = csv_reader.next()
header.append('F') #add new column

records = [header]

#process records
for record in csv_reader:
    #skip blank records
    if record == []:
        continue
    #make sure column "B" has 2 parts
    try:
        part1, part2 = record[1].split('_')
    except:
        continue
    #make sure part1 is a digit
    if not part1.isdigit():
        continue
    record[1] = part1 #make column B equal part1
    record.append(part2) #add data for the new column F to record
    records.append(record)

new_csv_file = open('out.csv', 'wb')
csv_writer = csv.writer(new_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for r in records:
    csv_writer.writerow(r)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why use the CSV module. A CSV is made up of text lines (strings) and you can use the Python string power (split, join, replace, len) to create your result.

line_cols = line.split(',') and back: line = ','.join(line_cols)

Comment: Why use the csv module? Because it hides a lot of the hassle of making sure strings get handled properly. Do you always check that all of your strings are quoted with the right quote characters if they contain whatever the current field separator character is? Why would you want to handle this manually for anything but the simplest output?

Comment: You are absolutely right, when you have to process CSV's from multiple sources.

Comment: -1: Reinventing the wheel is bad. Use the `csv` module which handles nearly any delimiter-separated file format, including strange edge cases.